# simple georef not working in CartoDB

Tags: carto, geocoding

I'm trying to georeference a table by administrative region, but none of my rows are referencing. I have the country name (listed as my 'jurisdiction' column) but no dice. I can't figure out what CartoDB would be interpreting it as. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Could you give us more hints? In your screenshot it seems like the geometries are already there (aka, your table is already geocoded)! When you import a file which contains country names which seems fine to georeference, CartoDB does it automatically. Check the "map view", your geometries should be there!

Answer (score 1):

Your table is already georeferenced! Go to "Map view" to see the geometries. :-) (Check that your "the_geom" column contains rows of type Polygon and that the cartodb_georef_status column is set to true.

If you want to run another georeferenciation process in your table, because for example not all your rows were correctly geocoded, make sure you delete the cartodb_georef_status column in advance. This column is used to keep the record of the rows that are already geocoded (or not), so any row with values true/false won't be geocoded again.

Rows with value "null" will be geocoded, and deleting the whole column will let you geocode your whole table again.

If you're georeferencing countries and some of them don't seem to work, I recommend you to use the official ISO3 code in order to geocoded them, this will also work, but names in general have a lot of variants and all of them may not be recognized by the system.